# How to implement a HashMap data structure in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, implementation

I want to implement a HashMap data structure, but I can't quite figure out what to do with underlying array structure.

If I'm not mistaken, in HashMap each key is hashed and converted into an integer which is used to refer to the array index. Search time is O(1) because of direct referring.

Let's say K is key and V is value. We can create an array of size n of V type and it will reside in the index produced by hash(K) function. However, hash(K) doesn't produce consecutive indices and Java's arrays aren't sparse and to solve this we can create a very large array to hold elements, but it won't be efficient, it will hold a lot of NULL elements.

One solution is to store elements in consecutive order, and for finding an element we have to search the entire array and check elements' keys but it will be linear time. I want to achieve direct access.

Thanks, beforehand.

Comment: is this a homework? can't you just use HashMap?

Comment: Map does not necessarily need hash and array. Explain what you need.

Comment: No it isn't, I was trying to implement my own versions of data structures, and some algorithms. My current DS was Map/Dictionary. I don't want to use HashMap, I want to implement one

Comment: @mentallurg I want to implement Hash Map

Comment: Learn from the masters: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: @MensurQulami: To *I can't quite figure out what to do with underlying array structure.* Don't use it. Don't care about it. You don't want to use HashMap. You want to implement **your own** solution. Why do you look at the HashMap then? Why do you ask about array? Just don't use an array and implement your own structure. Then what exactly is your problem?

Comment: In particular, the `putVal()` method [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l614)

Comment: @mentallurg, then how can that direct accessing be achieved?

Comment: There are many solutions possible: Linked List, Tree, ...

Comment: @mentallurg for finding an element in both we have to search, no? Especially in Linked List we have to traverse the list.

Comment: No necessarily. If you know the index for the list, you don't want to search, you don't want to compare anything. For a tree if you create hash in such a way that you can find needed node quickly, you don't need to search.

Comment: Why don't you take a good book like Cormen, Introduction to Algorithms, Chapter 11, Hash Tables? Here the different implementation alternatives are discussed with runtime behavior. Also worth reading is [Coding Geek: How does a HashMap work in JAVA](http://coding-geek.com/how-does-a-hashmap-work-in-java/).

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from the [Wikipedia article on hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Hashing), you can use a smaller array for underlying storage by taking the hash modulo the array size like so:

```
hash = hashfunc(key)
index = hash % array_size
```

This is a good solution because you can keep the underlying array relatively dense, you don't have to modify the hash funciton, and it does not affect the time complexity.

Comment: He does not want to use HashMap, does not want to copy & paste it. He wants to implement his own structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source code for all your problems.

For the sake of not going through a pretty large code. The solution to your problem is to use modulo. You can choose n=64, then store an element x with h(x) mod 64 = 2 in the second position of the array, ...

If two elements have the same hash modulo n, then you store them next to each other (usually done in a tree map). Another solution would be to increase n.

Comment: This is how HashMap works. But said he does not want to use HashMap, does not want to copy & paste it. He wants to implement his own structure.

Comment: "I want to implement a HashMap data structure", he just wants to do it himself, probably because he wants to learn how it works

Comment: "I don't want to use HashMap" - means he does not want to use the code, the approach in this class. He wants to implement his own solution.

Comment: @mentallurg, no, Thijs Steel is correct, just to learn how it works.

Comment: OK. Then why don't you go through each method in debugger and just ask "why" to each line of the code?